# Angular JS Bind radio buttons to variable to use as a flip

Tags: html, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

What I am trying to do is use the radio button value chosen by the user to update the variable in the controller. That variable depending on the value will do an http call for the specific answer.

**Example:**

Chose cars -> variable temp = cards -> http calls cars method

Chose house -> variable temp = house -> http calls house method

**In the view I have something like this:**

```
<input id ="inputOne" type="radio" ng-value="cars" ng-model="controller.selection">
<input id ="inputTwo" type="radio" ng-value="house" ng-model="controller.selection">

<input id="mySubmit" type="button" ng-click="controller.selectionChosen">
```

**In my Controller I have something like this:**

```
var vm=this;
vm.selection;

function selectionChosen(){
  alert(vm.selection);

  // If selection == cars do this
  // If selection == house do this
}
```

You might wonder why it is 'controllerName.variableName', I am following best practices ([found here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#single-responsibility)) `so the way it is set up requires controller name then the variable.

My problem I am having is for some reason the value is not binding. When the alert happens it alerts 'undefined' and I am not sure why. I have looked at many tutorials and examples online and this looks like it should work.

### Update

So I am pretty sure it is binding or at least trying to. When I set the variable initialized to "test" the first alert shows "test". After clicking a button then it goes to 'undefined".

Comment: To troubleshoot, I'd recommend verifying that controller in your view is actually referencing your controller as you expect.

Comment: It is, I am using other variables in the view and they are working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from the `ng-value="cars"`

since you are using Mycontroler as controller it should be `ng-value='controller.cars'` if you declare cars in your controller

If you just want to use cars as a string in ng-value without declare it, you need to add `' '`, angular will undestand it like a string instead of a variable
`ng-value="'cars'"`

Comment: I am trying your solution, can you also show how the controller should look so I know I am following your logic correctly?

Comment: i used a ng-repeat (for the checkbox) and didn t use vm but it worked for me
http://jsfiddle.net/15u9zpmu/2/

Comment: maybe your ng-value afre wrong, since you use controller as it should be 

`<input id ="inputTwo" type="radio" ng-value="controller.house" ng-model="controller.selection">`

or for  a string
`<input id ="inputTwo" type="radio" ng-value="'house'" ng-model="controller.selection">`

Comment: Tried that as well

Comment: Got it too Work :), I used your string implementation one, thats exactly what I wanted! Can you add that To your question with a description explaining the logic? Then I will accept and vote up. Thanks!

Comment: Because other people might not have a basic understanding of Angular. Thanks again